# how to replace the default ssh key to get access to docker-machine

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine to create a develop environment. I want to change the docker-machine default ssh key.

I check the config of my new machine:

```
docker-machine config develop
--tlsverify --tlscacert="/Users/robe/.docker/machine/machines/develop/ca.pem" --tlscert="/Users/robe/.docker/machine/machines/develop/cert.pem" --tlskey="/Users/robe/.docker/machine/machines/develop/key.pem" -H=tcp://192.168.99.103:2376
```

when I try to access using the key:

`--tlskey="/Users/robe/.docker/machine/machines/develop/key.pem"`

With this command:

```
ssh -i /Users/robe/.docker/machine/machines/develop/key.pem docker@192.168.99.103
```

Then I got the prompt to write password. So Why I can't access to my virtual machine using this access key.

- Do I need to do any other configuration?
- Is possible to specify a new key?
- What is the docker user password to get access using ssh key connection?

Any help please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key you're attempting to use is an SSL key used to protect the SSL connection to the remote docker agent. It is not an SSH key (different format).

SSH keys are generated for each machine created. Try the following command to obtain ssh access:

```
docker-machine ssh development
```

A more convoluted solution would be:

```
ssh -i ~/.docker/machine/machines/development/id_rsa docker@$(docker-machine ip development)
```

Comment: That was the solution.

Comment: I was able to use the second solution to ssh into the docker host and also set up port forwarding to my local box, which you can't do with the normal docker-machine ssh.

Comment: @Suchipi perhaps it was only recently added, but local forwarding worked ok with `docker-machine ssh name -L 5000:localhost:5000`

Comment: You can also add key permanently with `ssh-add <key>` and connect using `ssh root@<ip-addr>`.